# Is there a way I can wait for the outcome of multiple promises in an angular-ui-router resolve?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

Currently my code looks like this:

```
 resolve: {
            adminTestLevel: ['testService', (tes: ITestService) => {
                return tes.getAdminTestLevel();
            }],
            adminTestStatus: ['testService', (tes: ITestService) => {
                return tes.getAdminTestStatus();
            }],
            adminTestType: ['testService', (tes: ITestService) => {
                return tes.getAdminTestType();
            }],
            adminTestGradeType: ['testService', (tes: ITestService) => {
                return tes.getAdminTestGradeType()
            }],
            exams: ['testService', (tes: ITestService) => {
                return tes.getExams();
            }],
            examTypes: ['testService', (tes: ITestService) => {
                return tes.getExamTypes();
            }],
            testOrderBy: ['testService', (tes: ITestService) => {
                return tes.getTestOrderBy();
            }],
            topics: ['testService', (tes: ITestService) => {
                return tes.getTestsTopics();
            }],
        },
```

Is there a way that I could simplify this so that I don't have to have so many injections of the ITestService? Also I don't need to have all the different resolves and if possible I would like to combine these into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to use `$q.all(promises)`

from documentation for ([$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)):

> `$q.all(promises);`
>   Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.

so you can combine multiple promises in an array of promises and wait for resolve. you code could look like:

```
resolve: {
    required_data: function($q, testService) {
        return $q.all([
            testService.getAdminTestLevel(),
            testService.getAdminTestStatus(),
            testService.getAdminTestType()

            // and so on for all other promises
        ])
    }
}
```

then in your controller, also from the same documentation

> `$q.all(promises)`
>   Returns a single promise that will be resolved with an array/hash of values, each value corresponding to the promise at the same index/key in the promises array/hash

you could access the result from `required_data` injected into your controller.
for example `adminTestLevel` will be available at `required_data[0]` ... and so on, in the same order you have created your promise array in router.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $q.all

```
resolve: {
    myDate: function($q, tes) {     
        return $q.all([tes.getAdminTestLevel(), ... , tes.getTestsTopics()]);
    }
}
```

`myData` will only resolve after all the promises in the array will resolve

`$q.all` will give you an array of results you can use in your controller, you could access them by index so it's less convenient then plain injection.